# Centralizer is nontrivial

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $|G| = p^n$ where p is a prime number then $Z(G) \ne e.$

I don't understand a couple of parts of my book's proof.

It says, if $a\in G$, since $N(a)$ is a subgroup of G, $|N(a)|$, being a divisor of $|G| = p^n$, must be of the form $|N(a)| = p^{n_a}$; $a\in Z(G)$ if and only if $n_a = n$. Let $z = |Z(G)|$ we get $p^n = \sum (p^n/p^{n_a})$ however since there are exactly $z$ elements such that $n_a = n$ we find that $$p^n = z + \sum_{n_a <n}(p^n/p^{n_1}).$$

1.) Why is $a\in Z(G)$ if and only if $n_a = n$?

2.) Why are there z elements and why does that imply $n_a = n$ thus $$p^n = z + \sum_{n_a <n}(p^n/p^{n_1})?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\in Z(G)$ then $N(a) = G$ since everything in $G$ commutes with $a.$  Thus 
$$n_a = |N(a)| = |G| = n.$$

Conversely, if $n_a = n$ then $|N(a)| = |G|$ and since $N(a) \leq G$ it follows that $N(a) = G.$  But then every element of $G$ commutes with $a$ so $a\in Z(G).$

There are $z$ elements in $Z(G)$ by definition.  It might be that $z = 1$ but if $z=1$ then the class equation you have written would give you the contradiction that $p|1.$  Thus $z$ can not equal 1.

---

**EDIT**: The sum you've written

$$p^n = z + \sum_{n_a <n}(p^n/p^{n_1}).$$

is just the class equation.  More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation)

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain a little further on how they got $p^n = z + \sum_{n_a <n}(p^n/p^{n_1}).
$?

Comment: @user104235 I've edited my answer to include a link to the wiki page about the class equation.  If that doesn't help look in your book and review the orbit stabilizer theorem (might not be stated in those terms) which proves that the size of an orbit is equal to the index of the stabilizer.

Comment: Of course it is! I understand now, thank you very much!